# Relation between singular value, eigen value and 2-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-norms

I am confused.
We have that,
$ \sigma_{max} \ge \rho(A) = \|A\|_2$.

where $ \rho(A) = |\lambda_{max}|$ and $\sigma$ is the singular value of A.
And, $\sigma^2 = \lambda(A^*A)$.

But, $\rho(A) \ne \sqrt{\rho(A^*A)}$.

Comment: $\rho(A)$ is not equal to $\| A \|_2$ unless $A$ is normal. In general we have $\sigma_{max} = \| A \|_2$ (assuming that by this you mean the operator norm with respect to the $2$-norm).

Comment: Ok thanks! But $\sigma^2 = \lambda(A^*A)$?

Comment: You mean $\rho(A^{\ast} A)$? Yes.

Comment: Where $\rho(A^*A)=max(\lambda(A^*A))$